# Check if innerHTML is empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dom-events

I have a ajax call on my `onkeyup` event, that checks if the given email address is in the database or not. My problem is, that I can't find a right solution to check if the ajax response is EMPTY and if yes I need to disable a button.

This is the ajax.php output:

```
$sql = "// the query";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows>0){
    echo "<i>Yepp, this is taken</i>";
  }
```

This is the JavaScript for the ajax call AND the button disable and enable function (ajax call only if the email address is valid):

```
function checkEmail(str){

    email = document.getElementById('user-email').value
    AtPos = email.indexOf("@")
    StopPos = email.lastIndexOf(".")

    if (AtPos == -1 || StopPos == -1) {
         document.getElementById('button-reg').disabled=true;    
    }else{
        if (str=="")
          {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
          return;
          }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    var htmlstring = document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML;

    htmlstring = htmlstring.replace(/^\s+/,'');
    
    if(htmlstring==""){
        document.getElementById('button-reg').disabled=false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('button-reg').disabled=true;
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried with whitespace elimination, but no luck... after empty response the button is still not disabled...

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: did you try to add a "return" after if (AtPos == -1 || StopPos == -1) ? Currently the last 11 lines of the function are called every time you call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function..

```
function checkEmail(str){

    email = document.getElementById('user-email').value
    AtPos = email.indexOf("@")
    StopPos = email.lastIndexOf(".")

    if (AtPos == -1 || StopPos == -1) {
         document.getElementById('button-reg').disabled=true;    
    }else{
        if (str=="")
          {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
          return;
          }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

                htmlstring = xmlhttp.responseText.replace(/^\s+/,'');
                if(htmlstring==""){
                    document.getElementById('button-reg').disabled=false;
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('button-reg').disabled=true;
                }
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: i replaced but still not working... :( the "document.getElementById('button-reg').disabled=false;" JS is not executed...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
var isEmpty = (xmlhttp.responseText + "").length==0;
```

Perhaps you can write your program to be more interesting.

```
$out = array("ok"=>true,"msg"=>"Not data found","html"=>"<h1>Not <i>data</i> found</h1>");
echo json_encode($out);
```

Then on the client, load the json as data, and do  if(data["ok"])...  This way you can pass more than one parameter from the server to the client, and have these parameters separated. Make so the client part can choose easily what part to use, and have everything properly encoded so you don't have problems with utf-8.  Plus inspectors like Firebug will render the parameters nicelly if you have some json extension.